# Get Facebook User ID OnMapLongClickListener android

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps

i want to pass via intent the facebook ID, in google map.

I have a OnMapLongClickListener to get Latlng and pass via intent, and i want to pass facebook user id too...how can i do this?

OnMapLongClickListener

```
googlemap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latlng) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,newEvent.class);
            LatLng posicao = latlng;
            LatLng posicao1 = latlng;
            intent.putExtra("posicao", posicao);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable("posicao1", posicao1);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", args);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

i retrieve the facebook id in this method

```
  // METHODS FACEBOOK
public void onSessionStateChanged(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception){
    if(session != null && session.isOpened()){

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Conectado!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if(user != null){  
                //final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idface);

                    //tv.setText(user.getId());

                    Log.i("Script", "Usuário conectado " + user.getId());
                    getFriends(session);
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
    else{
        Log.i("Script", "Usuario não conectado");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `putExtra` as you did for the `LatLng`?

Comment: how to take the variable of the facebook method and pass via putextra in OnMapLongClickListener?

Comment: Cache the facebook id in a local variable, and reference it in `onMapLongClick`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: do you have an example how to this? im new in android  dev

Comment: I don't, but if you make your class `implement` `OnMapLongClickListener` (instead of using `new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener()`), it will have access to all local variables. Have a look at [this code sample](https://github.com/gizmonerd/Capstone/blob/master/src/com/csumb/viewer/MainActivity.java).

Comment: im lost lol...i cant find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an Android or Java dev environment, so this might not compile, but this should give you an idea. The facebook user ID is stored inside a field called `userId`. I've called your activity `MyActivity` - I assume your code is inside an activity

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnMapLongClickListener
{
    private String userId;

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latlng) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,newEvent.class);
        LatLng posicao = latlng;
        LatLng posicao1 = latlng;
        intent.putExtra("posicao", posicao);
        intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("posicao1", posicao1);
        intent.putExtra("bundle", args);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onSessionStateChanged(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception){
    if(session != null && session.isOpened()){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Conectado!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if(user != null){  
                    //final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idface);

                    userId = user.getId();

                    Log.i("Script", "Usuário conectado " + user.getId());
                    getFriends(session);
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
    else{
        Log.i("Script", "Usuario não conectado");
    }
}
```

The code below will be called as you currently do, from somewhere inside your `Activity`:

```
googlemap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution...

im using `SharedPreferences`

```
 SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                    p.edit().putString("FB_ID", loginId).commit();
```

and then

```
    final SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                final String username = p.getString("FB_ID", "");
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("facebook", username);
                intent.putExtra("facebook", args);
```

thanks

Comment: This is a misuse of preferences - that isn't what it's for.